# the number of iterations of >>>> "for(int i=start;i<num;i++)" i

Tags: java

i'm talking about for loops in that form  for(int i=0;i<5;i++)

i was  expecting that the increment statement is done after the check and i think i wrote  programs depending on that concept .

the problem is that when i tried to run that code

```
`for( int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
  System.out.println(i);
}
```

i was surprised to find the doesn't include 5
the output was 
0
1
2
3
4

i'm confused with this i think the statments must be executed at its order

Comment: The condition is `i<5`. Is `5 < 5`? No, it is not. So the loop will not run.

Answer (score 1):

Write it like this `i<=5`:

```
  for( int i = 0; i<=5; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
  }
```

Output:

```
 0
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
```

Comment: okay  i understand this very well , i'm just talking about the sequence of execution  in this loop  ... what should be run first ..the check or the increment  statment

Answer (score 0):

The sequence of a `for` loop is something like this:

```
Perform the initial expression (e.g. assign initial values)
BEGINNING OF 1ST LOOP ITERATION:
Check if the condition is true, and end the loop if it isn't
Do the body of the loop
Increment
BEGINNING OF 2ND LOOP ITERATION:
Check if the condition is true, and end the loop if it isn't
Do the body of the loop
Increment
BEGINNING OF 3RD LOOP ITERATION:
Check if the condition is true, and end the loop if it isn't
Do the body of the loop
Increment
...
```

And so on.  As you see the increment is done just before each check, not after the check as you thought.

Answer (score 0):

The statement within the loop runs first and then increments the value of 'i'. This is how `i++` functions, it will have i=0 for first loop and so on. So, on the 5th iteration i will be equal to 4.

*As soon as i becomes 5 after executing the statements for 5th time, it no longer satisfies the condition `i<5` and exits the loop.*

**In Java, typically the indexing starts from 0.**

But still, if you want 1,2,3,4 and 5 as indexes. Use `for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you do not get a 5 is because of the logic operator <.

```
i = 0;
is i < 5? Yes.
[..] i = 5; is i < 5? No. 5 < 5 is false.

for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
{ System.out.println(i); }
```

This will give you 5 since you check if it is equal to it.